# Sorting a list of dictionaries by its second value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to sort a list of dictionaries by its second value.

I tried everything but can't figure it out.

Here is my list of dictionaries:

```
[{'P3': [7, 117]}, {'P8': [14, 88]}, {'P2': [19, 102]}, {'P4': [19, 9]}]
```

Desired outcome:

```
[{'P4': [19, 9]}, {'P8': [14, 88]}, {'P2': [19, 102]}, {'P3': [7, 117]}]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So for each dictionary, you need to extract the second number of the only value in the dictionary.

You can get the list of values in a dictionary `D` by calling `D.values()`.  Since you want the first value (since there's only one), that's `D.values()[0]`...if you're using Python 2. In Python 3, the `values()` method returns a `dict_values` type rather than a list, so you want `list(D.values())[0]` (which will also work in Python 2).

You want the second element of the resulting list, so that's `list(D.values())[0][1]`.

Putting that together, we get:

```
>>> p=[{'P3': [7, 117]}, {'P8': [14, 88]}, {'P2': [19, 102]}, {'P4': [19, 9]}]
>>> sorted(p, key=lambda D: list(D.values())[0][1])
[{'P4': [19, 9]}, {'P8': [14, 88]}, {'P2': [19, 102]}, {'P3': [7, 117]}]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized the question I asked was very similar to the one i asked yesterday. Here is the code that worked for me: sorted(d, key=lambda i: list(i.values())[0][1])

Comment: i know i didn't ask this question, but when i copy and run it in pycharm or idle, i get  `TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing` error. it works when i do ` list(i.values())[0][1])`

Comment: @MaverickD you're probably using Python 3, so try `sorted(p, key=lambda D: list(D.values())[0][1])`. I've updated the answer, since that will work in both python 2 and 3.

Answer (score -1):

In python 2:

```
result = sorted(yourlist, key = lambda x : x.values()[0][1])
```